# Can my Cocoa pod and workspace use different versions of swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm playing around with some pods but most of the ones I am interested in were built in old versions of Swift (Swift 2 circa 2015)

When I open them XCode wants to update the syntax, which breaks everything.

Is there a way to keep the pods in the old syntax but use the latest syntax for all my new code? It seems like this is a pretty serious problem with using pods or am I missing something?

Comment: no you can't. both the pods and your project need to be using the same version. It has caused us a few issues previously when updating our projects to the latest Swift versions.